# How to combine/merge data from two tables having date range into single timeline query

Tags: sql, oracle

`XXA` - table which contains price for items based on date range.

`XXB` - table has new price for items based on date range.

Now I want `XXA` table to be updated based on new prices from `XXB` table considering date range.

If some dates are missing in new `XXB` table then for those dates old data should be maintained in `XXA`.

For example:

Table `XXA` contents:

```
 ITEM | PRICE | START_DATE | END_DATE
---------------------------------------
 plug |  12   | 10-Jan-15  | 15-Jan-15
 plug |   1   | 20-Jan-15  | 25-Jan-15
 plug |   3   | 30-Jan-15  |  4-Feb-15
 plug |   4   |  5-Feb-15  | 10-Feb-15
 plug |  43   | 20-Feb-15  | 25-Feb-15
```

Table `XXB` contents:

```
 ITEM | PRICE | START_DATE | END_DATE
---------------------------------------
 plug |  345  |  1-Jan-15  | 10-Jan-15
 plug |  133  | 12-Jan-15  | 20-Jan-15
 plug |  344  | 27-Jan-15  |  3-Feb-15
 plug |  455  |  7-Feb-15  | 10-Feb-15
 plug |  431  | 17-Feb-15  | 23-Feb-15
```

Now based on `XXB` data, `XXA` table should be changed like below, where the new price from `XXA` table is updated for available date ranges, for other dates old price in `XXA` is considered.

```
 ITEM | PRICE | START_DATE | END_DATE
---------------------------------------
 plug |  345  |  1-Jan-15  | 10-Jan-15
 plug |   12  | 11-Jan-15  | 11-Jan-15
 plug |  133  | 12-Jan-15  | 20-Jan-15
 plug |    1  | 21-Jan-15  | 25-Jan-15
 plug |  344  | 27-Jan-15  |  3-Feb-15
 plug |    3  |  4-Feb-15  |  4-Feb-15
 plug |    4  |  5-Feb-15  |  6-Feb-15
 plug |  455  |  7-Feb-15  | 10-Feb-15
 plug |  431  | 17-Feb-15  | 23-Feb-15
 plug |   43  | 24-Feb-15  | 25-Feb-15
```

**NOTE:** I suppose, Only if we bring the output in single sql query we can use it to update the table `XXA` accordingly. When i tried by taking individual scenario wise result goes wrong when data changes. Can somebody help me bring above output in single query.

Below is the code which i tried scenario wise:

```
with date_range as (select least(xa.min_start_date, xb.min_start_date) range_start,
                           greatest(xa.max_end_date, xb.max_end_date) range_end
                    from   (select min(start_date) min_start_date,
                                   max(end_date) max_end_date
                            from   xxa) xa
                           cross join
                           (select min(start_date) min_start_date,
                                   max(end_date) max_end_date
                            from   xxb) xb), 
          dates as (select range_start + level -1 dt
                    from   date_range
                    connect by range_start + level -1 <= range_end),
      pivot_xxa as (select xxa.item,
                           xxa.price,
                           dts.dt,
                           'Exist' status
                    from   xxa
                           inner join dates dts on (dts.dt between xxa.start_date and xxa.end_date)),
      pivot_xxb as (select xxb.item,
                           xxb.price,
                           dts.dt,
                           'New' status
                    from   xxb
                           inner join dates dts on (dts.dt between xxb.start_date and xxb.end_date)),
            res as (select coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item) item,
                           coalesce(pxb.price, pxa.price) price,
                           coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt) dt,
                           row_number() over (partition by coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item) order by coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt))
                             - row_number() over (partition by coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item), coalesce(pxb.price, pxa.price),pxa.status,pxb.status order by coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt)) grp
                    from   pivot_xxa pxa
                           full outer join pivot_xxb pxb on (pxa.item = pxb.item
                                                             and pxa.dt = pxb.dt))

select item,
       price,
       min(dt) start_date,
       max(dt) end_date
from   res
group  by item,
          price,
          grp;
```

Comment: EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;   this is a bad practice as it hides all errors.  change Null; to RAISE;

Comment: Regarding exception - there is no point to do EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN  RAISE; Just remove it at all if there are no actions in case of exception.

Comment: @sat33man: why period from 27-Jan-15  to 3-Feb-15 has value 344 in result? This period is defined in both tables. Why did you take it from XXB but not from XXA?

Comment: @Rusty because xxb table has the new price so i need to update xxa table with price values in xxb table considering date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, although it needed the creation of a global temporary table, since I couldn't work out how to merge the rows back into xxa (temporary brain fart, or genuinely not doable; I'm not sure! Open to ideas *{:-) ). Anyway, no need for PL/SQL, except as a wrapper for the insert/delete statements below.

```
create table xxa (item varchar2(5),
                  price number,
                  start_date date,
                  end_date date);

create table xxb (item varchar2(5),
                  price number,
                  start_date date,
                  end_date date);

create global temporary table xxa_xxb_tmp_res (item varchar2(5),
                                               price number,
                                               start_date date,
                                               end_date date);

insert into xxa
select 'plug', 12, to_date('10/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('15/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 1, to_date('20/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('25/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 3, to_date('30/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('04/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 4, to_date('05/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 43, to_date('20/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('25/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;

insert into xxb
select 'plug', 345, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 133, to_date('12/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('20/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 344, to_date('27/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('03/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 455, to_date('07/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 431, to_date('17/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('23/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;

commit;

insert into xxa_xxb_tmp_res (item, price, start_date, end_date)
with date_range as (select least(xa.min_start_date, xb.min_start_date) range_start,
                           greatest(xa.max_end_date, xb.max_end_date) range_end
                    from   (select min(start_date) min_start_date,
                                   max(end_date) max_end_date
                            from   xxa) xa
                           cross join
                           (select min(start_date) min_start_date,
                                   max(end_date) max_end_date
                            from   xxb) xb), 
          dates as (select range_start + level -1 dt
                    from   date_range
                    connect by range_start + level -1 <= range_end),
      pivot_xxa as (select xxa.item,
                           xxa.price,
                           dts.dt
                    from   xxa
                           inner join dates dts on (dts.dt between xxa.start_date and xxa.end_date)),
      pivot_xxb as (select xxb.item,
                           xxb.price,
                           dts.dt
                    from   xxb
                           inner join dates dts on (dts.dt between xxb.start_date and xxb.end_date)),
            res as (select coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item) item,
                           coalesce(pxb.price, pxa.price) price,
                           coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt) dt,
                           row_number() over (partition by coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item) order by coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt))
                             - row_number() over (partition by coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item), coalesce(pxb.price, pxa.price) order by coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt)) grp
                    from   pivot_xxa pxa
                           full outer join pivot_xxb pxb on (pxa.item = pxb.item
                                                             and pxa.dt = pxb.dt))
select item,
       price,
       min(dt) start_date,
       max(dt) end_date
from   res
group  by item,
          price,
          grp;


delete from xxa where item in (select item from xxa_xxb_tmp_res);

insert into xxa (item, price, start_date, end_date)
select item, price, start_date, end_date
from xxa_xxb_tmp_res;

commit;

select * from xxa
order by item, start_date;

ITEM       PRICE START_DATE END_DATE  
----- ---------- ---------- ----------
plug         345 01/01/2015 10/01/2015
plug          12 11/01/2015 11/01/2015
plug         133 12/01/2015 20/01/2015
plug           1 21/01/2015 25/01/2015
plug         344 27/01/2015 03/02/2015
plug           3 04/02/2015 04/02/2015
plug           4 05/02/2015 06/02/2015
plug         455 07/02/2015 10/02/2015
plug         431 17/02/2015 23/02/2015
plug          43 24/02/2015 25/02/2015

drop table xxa;
drop table xxb;
drop table xxa_xxb_tmp_res;
```

The bulk of the work is being done in the first insert statement - basically, what I'm doing is expanding the ranges in each table into individual rows, then full outer joining them, before taking the xxb table's columns in preference to xxa's. Once I have that information, then I use the [tabibitosan](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1007478?tstart=0) method to re-group the results back into ranges.

---

Ok, here's a way to do it using a merge, but it does mean that the xxa table needs to have a primary key (or some other column that identifies the rows for each item). N.B. If there are more rows in the xxa table than the combined xxa/xxb results have, the "extra" rows will have nulls in the price, start_date and end_date column. (I still think these rows should be deleted!):

```
create table xxa (pk_col number,
                  item varchar2(5),
                  price number,
                  start_date date,
                  end_date date,
                  constraint xxa_pk primary key (pk_col));

create table xxb (item varchar2(5),
                  price number,
                  start_date date,
                  end_date date);

create sequence xxa_seq
  start with 1
  maxvalue 999999999999999999999999999
  minvalue 1
  nocycle
  cache 20
  noorder;

insert into xxa
select xxa_seq.nextval,
       item,
       price,
       start_date,
       end_date
from   (select 'plug' item, 12 price, to_date('10/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') start_date, to_date('15/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') end_date from dual union all
        select 'plug', 1, to_date('20/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('25/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'plug', 3, to_date('30/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('04/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'plug', 4, to_date('05/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'fork', 10, to_date('02/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('20/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'fork', 20, to_date('22/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('28/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'fork', 30, to_date('01/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'club', 10, to_date('02/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('20/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'club', 20, to_date('22/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('28/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
        select 'club', 30, to_date('01/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual);

insert into xxb
select 'plug', 345, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 133, to_date('12/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('20/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 344, to_date('27/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('03/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 455, to_date('07/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('10/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'plug', 431, to_date('17/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('23/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'fork', 15, to_date('15/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('18/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'fork', 25, to_date('24/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('08/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
select 'club', 100, to_date('03/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('20/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;

commit;

merge into xxa tgt
using (with date_range as (select least(xa.min_start_date, xb.min_start_date) range_start,
                                  greatest(xa.max_end_date, xb.max_end_date) range_end
                           from   (select min(start_date) min_start_date,
                                          max(end_date) max_end_date
                                   from   xxa) xa
                                  cross join
                                  (select min(start_date) min_start_date,
                                          max(end_date) max_end_date
                                   from   xxb) xb), 
                 dates as (select range_start + level -1 dt
                           from   date_range
                           connect by range_start + level -1 <= range_end),
             pivot_xxa as (select xxa.item,
                                  xxa.price,
                                  dts.dt
                           from   xxa
                                  inner join dates dts on (dts.dt between xxa.start_date and xxa.end_date)),
             pivot_xxb as (select xxb.item,
                                  xxb.price,
                                  dts.dt
                           from   xxb
                                  inner join dates dts on (dts.dt between xxb.start_date and xxb.end_date)),
                   res as (select coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item) item,
                                  coalesce(pxb.price, pxa.price) price,
                                  coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt) dt,
                                  row_number() over (partition by coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item) order by coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt))
                                    - row_number() over (partition by coalesce(pxb.item, pxa.item), coalesce(pxb.price, pxa.price) order by coalesce(pxa.dt, pxb.dt)) grp
                           from   pivot_xxa pxa
                                  full outer join pivot_xxb pxb on (pxa.item = pxb.item
                                                                    and pxa.dt = pxb.dt)),
             final_res as (select item,
                                  price,
                                  min(dt) start_date,
                                  max(dt) end_date,
                                  row_number() over (partition by item order by min(dt)) rn
                           from   res
                           group  by item,
                                     price,
                                     grp),
                xxa_rn as (select pk_col,
                                  item,
                                  price,
                                  start_date,
                                  end_date,
                                  row_number() over (partition by item order by start_date) rn
                           from   xxa)
       select coalesce(fr.item, xa.item) item,
              fr.price,
              fr.start_date,
              fr.end_date,
              xa.pk_col
       from   final_res fr
              full outer join xxa_rn xa on (fr.item = xa.item and fr.rn = xa.rn)) src
  on (tgt.item = src.item and tgt.pk_col = src.pk_col)
when matched then
update set tgt.price = src.price,
           tgt.start_date = src.start_date,
           tgt.end_date = src.end_date
when not matched then
insert (pk_col, tgt.item, tgt.price, tgt.start_date, tgt.end_date)
values (xxa_seq.nextval, src.item, src.price, src.start_date, src.end_date);

commit;

select * from xxa
order by item, start_date;

    PK_COL ITEM       PRICE START_DATE END_DATE  
---------- ----- ---------- ---------- ----------
         8 club          10 02/01/2015 02/01/2015
         9 club         100 03/01/2015 20/02/2015
        10 club                                  
         5 fork          10 02/01/2015 14/01/2015
         6 fork          15 15/01/2015 18/01/2015
         7 fork          10 19/01/2015 20/01/2015
        27 fork          20 22/01/2015 23/01/2015
        26 fork          25 24/01/2015 08/02/2015
        22 fork          30 09/02/2015 10/02/2015
         1 plug         345 01/01/2015 10/01/2015
         2 plug          12 11/01/2015 11/01/2015
         3 plug         133 12/01/2015 20/01/2015
         4 plug           1 21/01/2015 25/01/2015
        25 plug         344 27/01/2015 03/02/2015
        23 plug           3 04/02/2015 04/02/2015
        28 plug           4 05/02/2015 06/02/2015
        21 plug         455 07/02/2015 10/02/2015
        24 plug         431 17/02/2015 23/02/2015

drop table xxa;
drop table xxb;
drop sequence xxa_seq;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works but i forgot to mention that xxa data should not be deleted as its seeded. Deleting data will not show history in audit report so i must only update/insert in that table. Let me try using this..after populating data in temp table using that will try to achieve it. If possible can you try without deleting as well. Anyway you are awesome.Thanks.

Comment: What if a single row in the xxb table covers the same range as two or more rows in the xxa table? You'd need to reduce the number of rows in xxa then, surely? Thinking about it, you could probably add a join in to the xxa table to the outer SQL stmt based on rownum and then use that to identify which start_date to join against in the merge. It'll make it even slower though. I'll have a look at that tomorrow.

Comment: Yes you are correct.Like xxa has 5-Sep-15 ,20-Sep-15 and 2-Sep-15,3-Sep-15 . XXB has 1-Sep-15,22-Sep-15. Now we have 1 extra line in xxa which should not be deleted. If query returns output like 1-Sep-15 ,4-Sep-15||5-Sep-15,20-Sep-15||21-Sep-15,22-Sep-15 then its fine. Except this scenario others as adjustable without deleting.

Comment: i edited your code and added in above question. I just included status column in XXA,XXB . Based on that while grouping separating dates. But still how to figure out which row to used for update of XXA and which one to insert directly to XXA? Any idea on this? Please help..

Comment: adding in the status column didn't actually do anything useful, though! However, I've updated my answer to include a way to merge the results. It does assume that xxa has a primary key, though. If your table doesn't, then you're going to have to add one.